# Removing punctuation in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, punctuation

I'm trying to remove punctuation from my tokenized text with regex. I'm using spark dataframes.
This is my function:

```
def removePunctuation(column):
     return trim(lower(regexp_replace(column,'[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]', ''))).alias('stopped')
```

When I'm executing this function by:

```
removed_df.select(removePunctuation(col('stopped'))).show(truncate=False)
```

I have the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o736.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'regexp_replace(`stopped`, '[^\\sa-zA-Z0-9]', '')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`stopped`' is of array<string> type.;;
```

Is there any way to remove punctuation by this function? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that your column `stopped` is of type `array<string>` rather than `string`. You need a string column for `regexp_replace`.

In order to apply if to an array of strings you can first create a string out of the array and then split that string again

```py
def removePunctuation(column):
     return split(trim(lower(regexp_replace(concat_ws("SEPARATORSTRING", column),'[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]', ''))), "SEPARATORSTRING").alias('stopped')
```

Comment: Sure, but how to do this? This is my column from dataframe, can I just simply change the type for string?

Comment: you'd need to first concat and then split the array on a separator. See the modified answer

Comment: I got something like this: TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <function concat_ws at 0x000000B9FE1E8438> of type <class 'function'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

`df=pysparkDF.withColumn('someColOfStrings', translate('someColOfStrings', '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_{|}~', ''))`

`tokenizer = Tokenizer(outputCol="textTokens")`

`tokenizer.setInputCol("someColOfStrings")`

`df1=tokenizer.transform(df.dropna())`

With this code, you can tokenize the values in the strings after you remove the punctuations.